# Count the number of Files modified in the last hour using linq

Tags: linq

```
    var query=from file in Directory.GetFiles(source_path, filename, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
              where File.GetLastWriteTime(file) >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
              select file;

    Console.Write(query.ToList().Count.ToString());
```

I'm using the above code to get the count of files modified in last one hour. Looking for a simpler solution. ie to have the count as part of the query itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Count()` can take a predicate:

```
Directory.GetFiles(source_path, filename, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Count(file => File.GetLastWriteTime(file) >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `Count()` on the query itself.

```
var source = Directory.GetFiles(source_path, filename, 
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
int count = (from file in source
            where File.GetLastWriteTime(file) >= timeStamp
            select file)
            .Count();

Console.Write(count);
```

A faster solution would be to use a [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) overload that takes in a predicate.